# Find objects with certain attribute in nested object with arrays inside

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I have an object that looks like kind like folder tree - i've got projects, projectsFolders with another projectFolders and projects inside. I want to find those which have the property 'selected'. Let's say that 1 of them could be:

```
myObj.projectFolders[3].projectFolders[2].projects[5]
```

where, for example [...]projects[5].selected = true

I can make a recursive function, but I've heard that there is some easy way to do it in Underscore. I'm trying to dig it some longer time, but without success :( Does anybody have a hint for me?

Comment: If your data is in nested arrays like your example, you could do something like: `_.chain(data).flatten().where({ selected: true }).value();`